# Edit wordpress wp_postmeta?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on a custom theme for my client, and I have nearly finished accept a very annoying problem with thumbnail sizes holding me up.

To cut a long story short, the new theme uses different sized post thumbnails (which I sent in functions.php) so I ran the thumbnail regeneration plug-in (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) and it worked fine on all but a few thumbnails.

Now, I have opted to resize those few remaining thumbs myself, but I need the meta_value in wp_postmeta to be updated to point to the resized thumbnails like all the others have been by the regeneration plug-in e.g. s:19:"resize2-188x188.jpg"; rather than just "resize2.jpg".

I would change this myself via the server’s cpanel but my client is away from a fortnight and I only have full admin access to his wordpress dashboard.

My question is, what is the simplest way to edit post meta? or perhaps you guys have another suggestion?

Im on a tight deadline with this one so any help much appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-options-manager/ looks like what you need.

Please, use some sort of backup plugin and backup your database before you manually change entries.